# Best practice for SQL table names when using sub namespaces that exceed maximum table name length

Tags: mysql, table, naming-convention, limits

I have a MySQL database that includes many tables named according to a namespace that uses sub names and underscores (`_` as in `a_b_c`), such as the following:

- life_domain_kingdom_phylum
- life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class
- life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order
- life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order_family
- life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order_family_genus
- life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order_family_genus_species
- ...etc...

...some of the namespace names exceed the database's maximum table name length (e.g., 64 characters).  The namespace itself is clear to me and would be sufficiently practical, if it were not for the database table name limit.

**How to deal with a namespace that exceeds 64-characters and a database that has a maximum 64-character table name limit?**  The following options come to mind...

- Extend the database's table name length limit.  However, this does not seem practical, possible, and/or good practice.  Otherwise, this would be a nice solution, because I would be able to continue using my current namespace.
- Shorten the names by using only the sub-name, such as `kingdom`.  However, this creates ambiguity with other naming constructs in the same namespace (e.g., `class` may be confused with `school_x_program_x_class` or `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class`) and may intersect at some level.
- Shorten the names by using only the first few characters of each sub name.  For example, rename `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order_family_genus_species` to `lif_dom_kin_phy_cla_ord_fam_gen_spe`.  However, the shortened names are difficult to comprehend.
- Create a limited length, unique hash for each namespace name, then use an external tool to map the hashed names to the actual/desired/full namespace names, then name the tables using the hashed names and refer to them using the external tool.  For example, the namespace name `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class` maps to the table name `asd8fjkd8f`, and the namespace name `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order` maps to the table name `ifuel9kf03l`.  Although this option seems to depend on an external mapping tool, it seems to be the most flexible/practical.

I read the following posts, but they seem to discuss styling conventions rather than database table name length limitations:

- [How to properly name a database table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262159/how-to-properly-name-a-database-table)
- [Best name to name a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250023/best-name-to-name-a-table)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft
- [Is there a reason to use extremely abbreviated table names?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/is-there-a-reason-to-use-extremely-abbreviated-table-names?rq=1)

**UPDATE 2022-01-20**

Based on comments received, I realize I maybe should have used more examples than the biological tables (e.g., `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class...`).

The database includes other groups of tables, some of which are for storing one-to-many or many-to-many relationships, such as the following:

- group
- product
- derivative
- lab_result
- group_x_product
- group_x_product_x_derivative
- group_x_product_x_derivative_x_lab_result
- ...etc...

Comment: Surely those who are writing queries for this database are familiar with the Linnean system and biology in general? The `life_` bit appears to be redundant. Have d_k_p as an abbreviation for `domain_kindom_phylum` - that should give you all the space you need? I would suggest that this is a better solution than having tables name `ifuel9kf03l`!

Comment: What's wrong with just `phylum` , `class`  `order`, etc.? You have FKs that *enforce* the relationship. I can see a grouping (by different `life` groups) like `worldbuilder_stackexchange_genus` vs `real_species`

Comment: As pointed out by Michael, you should name a table after the direct object(s) it's data represents, regardless of where that object lives in the hierarchy of entities. Your table `life_domain_kingdom_phylum_class_order_family_genus_species` doesn't directly store all of the `lifes`, `nor all of the `kingdoms`, nor all of the `phylums, etc. It directly stored `species` so it should just be called `species` and it's foreign key relationship to it's parent entity `genus` (another table) should exist and explicitly define the hierarchy.

Comment: You may be interested in the public taxonomy data from https://itis.gov/ which stores all those entities in one table named `hierarchy`.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW.  Thank you for pointing out the Linnean system. I now notice the redundancy of `life_`.  Abbreviating may be confused with other names in the namespace that also have first characters as `d` and `p`.  I just updated my question to include examples of those names.

Comment: @MichaelKutz The problem with just `class` or `order` is that they are ambiguous, because the database includes those words as its sub names, such as `school_program_class`.

Comment: @J.D. Naming the table according to the direct object(s) is practical for some objects, but not all object.  For example, a table named `species` is practical, but a table named `class` is not practical because it is also used in the school namespace (e.g., `school_program_class`)

Comment: `lh_domain` (life hierarchy domain) is a parent to `lh_kingdom` which in turn is parent to `lh_phylum` - chose as many letters as you need for `lh` - even the full `life_hierarchy_xyz...` would do it - class, order... and so on down the line? No?

Answer (score 0):

There is essentially no reason to prefix tables with the database they are in.  Ditto for prefixing column names with the table names.  Keep in mind that these syntaxes can give you an equal amount of clutter, without threatening the max name lengths:

```
dbname.tablename

tablename.columnname
```

"Everybody" recognizes `genus_species`; I suggest that is sufficient for that table.